# Password hash being changed on database entry php

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, hash

Using password_hash() and hash a password and store it in DB, it will not pass password_verify. I tried testing the functions out just running a word through them outside of the database, that worked fine. And, if I hash a word, then manually put it in the database, it then works fine in the login. But, when I enter the hash into my database via my code/SQL...something apparently is happening to the hash at this point and making it unusable (from what I can tell). I can't figure out what. I checked my table..that seems fine, Varchar(255) utf8_bin.
I am using codeigniter framework. Codeigniter escapes it's inserts unless you do it with set like below and use FALSE - did not work.

```
function register($data){
    $this->db->set($data, FALSE);
    $this->db->set('word_of_passing', $data['word_of_passing'], FALSE);
    $this->db->insert('cred');
}
```

This did not work -

```
function register($data){
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO cred (user_name, word_of_passing) VALUES ("'.$data['user_name'].'", "'.$data['word_of_passing'].'")');
}
```

This did not work -

```
function register($data){
    $this->db->insert('cred', $data);       
}
```

And finally I just tried to go completely outside codeigniter with this..did not work -

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "moviedb";

    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO cred (user_name, word_of_passing) VALUES ('".$data['user_name']."', '".$data['word_of_passing']."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

My controller is like this -

```
public function check_pw(){
    //password and username post
    $data = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    //pass username to model to retrieve stored hash
    $this->load->model('lindsdata');
    $return_data = $this->lindsdata->password($data);
    //$pw is indeed getting the stored hash, but not passing
    $pw = password_verify($password, $return_data[0]['word_of_passing']);
    if ($pw == 1) {
        $this->session->set_userdata(array("logged_in" => "true",
                                                "user_id"  =>                   $return_data[0]['user_id']
                                                ));
    redirect('/update/user', 'location');           
    }else{
        $error['the_error'] = 'Your Credentials are wrong';
    }
}
```

All I can think is that it has to be a setting in my database or something? I am really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

if you insert problem in database i suggest you add like model function like you controller put model name and function

```
class Lindsdata extends CI_Modle{
public function password(){
 $data = array(
          'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'), 
          'word_of_passing' => $this->input->post('password'),    
        );

   $query = $this->db->insert('cred',$data);
   if($query)
    {
     return true;
    }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
} 
}
```

get in controller like

```
   $this->load->model('lindsdata');
    $return_data = $this->lindsdata->password();
```